# Plotting Data Iteratively

Tags: plotting, iteration

I have a function of x1 that I can plot in the form y=f(x1).  However, I have a relation y=f(x1)=f(x2), where I don't know the form of f(x2), but I can solve for x2 given f(x1) and I want to plot both on the same axis.  What I mean is that I have a range of values for y, which I plot for different x1 and x2, which I'd like to have on the same axis.

Comment: Can you give some example data? If you have a list of data try `ListPlot` if you look at the documentation you should find how to plot two sets of data.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining "the form of f(x2)" by `InverseFunction` and plotting `x1` and `x2`.

```
(* some random x data *)
x1 = Accumulate[Table[RandomInteger[10], 10]];

Clear[f, invf]
f[x_] := x^2 - 0.2 x + 3;
y = f /@ x1;

invf = Quiet[InverseFunction[f]];
x2 = invf /@ y;
ListPlot[{Transpose[{x1, y}], Transpose[{x2, y}]}]
```

[image]